# Error Starting VM on Vrtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-7

**I cannot start any VM in VirtualBox**
It stuck at `Starting Virtual Machine - 0%`

I'm getting the following error when I end the task:

```
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
SessionMachine
Interface: 
ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}
```

I'm getting similar errors with any VM and since it hangs up at 0% it seems to be a VirtualBox issue.

I am **using** VirtualBox 5.1.14 on Windows 10.
I **need** to start Ubuntu as well as CentOS VMs.

Kindly help or I might end up in trouble.

Comment: Did you try to download a pre-installed and working iso of the system you are interested in? E.g. you can check [for Ubuntu on virtualboxes.org](https://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/)

Comment: Nope. the issue was somewhere else. Check my comment to `@fernando's` answer

Comment: In that case, usually, it's enough to open the configuration file for the virtual machine and change there the path. Remember for the future to explain the steps you have done before the problem. It helps to find solutions. BTW welcome on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the omnisapient internet, you will fall into the VirtualBox forum outlining a problem like [yours](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33196), that has the next solution:

```
My Solution:
I went into the folder "C:\Users\COMPUTER_NAME\.VirtualBox\Machines\VM_NAME\" and saw two xml files but for some reason they both had suffixes. 
1. VM_NAME.xml-prev
2. VM_NAME.xml-tmp
So it simply just couldn't find "VM_NAME.xml" because it technically didn't exist.
I made a copy of the "VM_NAME.xml-prev" file and renamed the copy to "VM_NAME.xml"
Restarted VirtualBox and it worked just fine
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, in my case I had moved the original images from which I created the VMs to a different location: From C:\Users\Divij\Downloads to E:\Softs\Operating Systems, which was causing the problem. So I copied them to their original locations and restarted the machine. Whether it was restarting the machine that worked or copying the images to their original locations, I do not know, but the VMs booted up just fine after that.